# Share FirebaseAuth session between app and share extension (iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, share-extension

Is it possible to share the Firebase auth token between the main app and its share extension?

I currently have made a way to get the users uid by saving to NSUSERDefaults after login then accessing from the extension via App Groups, would this need a similar method with the token?

This is then to be able to fetch and set details for the user into the Firebase database from the extension.

Comment: Did you get solution of this ?